# I can't getcurrentuser from firebase auth

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

```
  Handler().postDelayed({
        FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener { auth ->
            val user = auth.currentUser
            if(user != null) {
                startProfileActivity()
            } else {
                startLoginActivity()
            }
        }
    },1500)
```

I have used firebase to make an auto authentication in my splash screen to check whether the user already login or not. However, what I found from the debugger is that I can't get the currentUser from firebase. The log does not give any detail either. Can anyone help me?

Comment: On Stack Overflow, don't post pictures of code.  You should copy the code into the question itself and format it so it's easy to read, copy, and search.

Comment: You can edit the question by using the edit link below the tags.

Answer (score 0):

An auth state listener isn't a function you can run to get the current user, as you're using it now.  It's a listener that asynchronously receives updates about the user's sign-in status. The listener will trigger when the user is known to be signed in or signed out.

You add instances of AuthStateListener using [addAuthStateListener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth#addAuthStateListener(com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener)), then remove the instance with [removeAuthStateListener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth#removeAuthStateListener(com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener)) when you're done.

You can check to see if the user is signed in at a given moment with `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser`, but that can change over time, and it will not reflect the status of the current user immediately when the app starts.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation. So, If I want to implement this kind of use case what kind of service of firebase can support this use-case?